# Record stored to Array and then pull random value while skipping first index position

Tags: php, arrays, random, slice

I want to be able to pull a single record from the database, store that record into an array, and then show a random value from that array, and that random value cannot be the 0 index position because that is the record's ID field.

I have two tables.  One is `questions` and the other is `answers`. `Questions` has two fields, `ID` and `Question`.  `Answers` has 10 fields: `ID, ANS1, ANS2, ANS3, etc.`  So, `Answers` is associated with `Questions` by their `ID`.

To get the record, I am using this:

```
$json = array( );
mysql_select_db($database_localhost, $localhost);
$query_getSentence = "SELECT * FROM answers WHERE ID = 13";
$getSentence = mysql_query($query_getSentence, $localhost) or die(mysql_error());
while ( $row_getSentence = mysql_fetch_assoc($getSentence)) {
$json[] = $row_getSentence;
$totalRows_getSentence = mysql_num_rows($getSentence);
```

So, when I use `print_r($json)`, I get this:

```
Array (
    [0] => Array (
        [ID] => 13
        [ANS1] => ducks
        [ANS2] => chickens
        [ANS3] => birds
        [ANS4] => cats
        [ANS5] => dogs
        [ANS6] => elephants
        [ANS7] => monkeys
        [ANS8] => animals 
        [ANS9] => bees
    )
)
```

Now, if I understand this correctly, I think you get a random result from an array using this:

```
echo $myArray[array_rand($myArray)];
```

But it doesn’t work if I put `$json` where I just wrote `$myArray`. I know I have to use `json_encode`, but no matter how many different ways I try to insert that in the above code, it doesn’t do anything still.

Also, to skip the first index (the ID field), the way I've tried it is doing this:

```
echo(array_slice($myArray,1,9));
```

That returns all the Answers and leaves out the ID.  But, once again, I can’t figure out how to combine all this stuff into a working piece of code.  How, do I use all of this together, so it works correctly?

Comment: What does `print_r($json);` output?

Comment: It prints the entire array.

Comment: You can't `echo` an array. You'll have to use either `print_r()` or `var_dump()` to output the contents, @SherwoodPro. Can you edit your question to include the output?

Comment: I'll do it right now.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about just using [`shuffle`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.shuffle.php) and grabbing the first item off of the array like this:

```
shuffle($myArray)
echo $myArray[0];
```

But honestly, your code is confusing. So what is the output of the `$json` array—that isn’t JSON—if you do this?

```
echo '<pre>';
print_r($json);
echo '</pre>';
```

**EDIT:** With the updated question from the original poster, it seems like the array is nested in another array based on the structure:

```
Array (
    [0] => Array (
        [ID] => 13
        [ANS1] => ducks
        [ANS2] => chickens
        [ANS3] => birds
        [ANS4] => cats
        [ANS5] => dogs
        [ANS6] => elephants
        [ANS7] => monkeys
        [ANS8] => animals 
        [ANS9] => bees
    )
)
```

Okay, so knowing that you would do this. I assuming that `$json` is the array in this case:

```
$new_array = array_slice($json[0],1,9);
$random_key = array_rand($new_array);
$final_value = $new_array[$key];
```

So `array_slice` is grabbing items 1-9 from `$json[0]` and assigning it to `$new_array`. Then we use `array_rand()` to get a random key value from  `$new_array`. Now the final value is set as `$final_value` with `$new_array[$key]`.

I am using `array_rand` here instead of the `shuffle` I used before because it’s clear you want to preserve keys.

Comment: Why would you use `shuffle()` over `array_rand()`?

Comment: Fair enough. `shuffle()` takes an array by reference and modifies the order of *all* array elements. `array_rand()` simply returns a random index, so I just prefer `array_rand()` over `shuffle()`.

Comment: I updated my question to show the output of my array.

Comment: I'm sorry, I just realized Dreamweaver changed my record request.  I didn't notice that.  I updated the code to my question.  I think whatever DW did screwed things up worse.  Figures.

Comment: When I put what you have, and put echo $final_value, nothing shows up.  Do you think the MySQL Dreamweaver changed is screwing it up?  That all makes great sense.  I was making it too difficult I think.  One more question, on the $final_value, is that being used so it doesn't keep picking random values from $new_array and commits it for me?

Comment: Yeah that makes it much better.  I'll start experimenting, and learning more about this so it all comes together for me.  I appreciate your help and direction.  : )